Do long vowel differ to their short counterparts beyond just being longer?
Please first look at the table below:



Short Vowels
IPA
Long Vowels
IPA




/æ/
as in "cat"




/ɛ/
as in "bed"
/iː/
as in "see"


/ɪ/
as in "sit"
/ɑː/
as in "father"


/ɒ/
as in "hot"
/ɔː/
as in "law"


/ʌ/
as in "cup"
/uː/
as in "too"


/ʊ/
as in "put"




/ə/
as in "sofa"





In the International Phonetic Alphabet, a special triangular colon-like letter is used to indicate that the preceding consonant or vowel is long. It seems that I cannot simply pronounce the short vowels longer to create the sound of the longer ones. e.g. /ɒ/ -> /ɒ:/
because the IPA is using another symbol for the long one /ɑː/
So are there noticeable differences in pronunciation of the  pairs below

/ɒ:/ and /ɑː/
/ʊ:/ and /ɔː/
/ɪ:/ and /iː/


If you have a look at the Cambridge dictionary online, you can search for a word and listen to a sound sample. For example: cat

You misunderstand the meanings of "short vowel" and "long vowel". When we say met is a "short e", and meet is a "long e", that doesn't mean the sound of the second one is just a longer version of the first. They're different sounds that happen to use the same letter when written (because of the way spoken language changes over generations, without much regard for spelling). In modern English it doesn't really matter if you shorten or stretch any specific vowel sound - they'll normally be perceived as the same vowel anyway.

The answer is IN THE CHART: /ɛ/ as in "bed" /iː/ as in "see", for example. They are all there. They are different vowel sounds leading to different minimal pars. bead v. bed

Their points of articulation are different.

Here’s a proofread version of your text:
@FumbleFingers My question clearly indicates that the IPA uses distinct symbols and not just a colon (":") to denote longer vowels. While it seems you read the question carelessly, you somewhat answered by stating that elongating a short vowel does not create a different phoneme. If you have any resources to support that claim, I would appreciate it.

Have a look at Steven Pinker Words and Rules, chapter 4. Specifically where he gives examples like flee-fled, shoot-shot and points out that 'long' and 'short' have been misnomers in English at least since the Great Vowel Shift in the fifteenth century, when people scrambled the pronunciations of vowels. Obviously those two "long-short" vowels (and other such pairs) are "related", since they are the mechanism by which we inflect those verbs for tense. But they're certainly not "the same sound" (with long or short enunciation).

@FumbleFingers thanks, may be create an answer from your comments for better visibility.

The Great Vowel Shift is the cause of the misnomers, but that's really just a matter of history (that partly explains how English got where it is today). But the important point is covered in @James's answer the actual timing is less important than the type of sound. There are no English word-pairs only differentiated by the actual "vowel sound" being lengthened or shortened.

In general, the length of a vowel sound is not as important in English as the quality of the sound.  For example /iː/ and /ɪ/ form a pair of vowels in which the first is generally "long" and the second is "short".  However the actual timing is less important than the type of sound.  In a word like "happy", the final /i/ but is usually quite short.  Native speakers would hear the final sound in "happy" as being like the vowel in "see", rather than the vowel in sit.
So for good pronunciation you should ensure that you are producing the right sound. If you pronounce "sit" as /sit/ native speakers will hear "seat" and this mistake is a common error among speakers of languages which lack the /ɪ/ vowel.
There are noticeable differences between the vowel pairs, and the quality is more important than the length in recognising words.

For me, it is quite easy to produce a short /i/  -  by "doing an accent".  It is typical of Spanish accents, for example.  It is difficult for me to do a long /ɪː/  That seems to be a strange and unnatural sound.

/iː/ is pronounceable for Spanish speakers. It's /i/ that doesn't exist in Spanish, so they say sheep instead of ship.

exactly, (some) Spanish speakers produce /ɪ/ by doing /i/ (a short form of /iː/) which native English speakers hear as the sound in "sheep" (long) rather than the sound in ship (short).  In English the length is less important than the quality of the vowel.

No, it's the other way around. Spanish does not have the "short form"of i as in bit, fit, and lip, which is /ɪ/. They don't produce it at all unless they specifically practice and learn it.

Exactly as I said.  Spanish does not have the  /ɪ/ phoneme, so (some) speakers of Spanish use a short /i/ instead when speaking English, and say /bit/ instead of /bɪt/  But for English speakers, the length of the vowel is less important than the quality, and /bit/ will be heard as being like /biːt/

@JamesK: There are no English word-pairs only differentiated by the actual "vowel sound" being lengthened or shortened. Have I gone out on a limb too far, there?

Phonetician (and screenwriter and director!) Geoff Lindsey argues convincingly, including on his YouTube channel—and in particular in his video entitled Why these English phonetic symbols are all WRONG—that the commonly encountered IPA transcriptions of English vowels are woefully misleading.

I dunno. See John Trim's book: khttps://assets.cambridge.org/97805212/06341/excerpt/9780521206341_excerpt.pdf I recknon these guys never actually had to teach English. What you mention is an academic debate really.

@Lambie, I don’t see it as an academic debate. Pedagogical, perhaps. But Lindsey is among other things, a speech and dialect coach, so his points are directly relevant to learners of English. Have you watched the video?

Have you seen the John Trim book? He covers all the vowel sounds using traditional IPA.

Lindsey uses traditional IPA too. He merely disputes the traditional transcriptions.

bead OR see is pronounced /biːd/. = right, as opposed to bid, which is /i/ or /bid/. I don't see why it's an issue.

@Lambie, I have gotten my own IPA screwed up. I need to adjust to correct my answer above.
